# every time I insert a size that's not 39, the console doesn't display anything, how can I fix this?

Tags: c#, if-statement, console-application

```
using System;

namespace deez
{
 class Hello
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            int size = 39;
            string color = "black";
            if (size == 40 && (color == "black" || color == "blue"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ok, i'm gonna take it");
            }
            else if (size <= 38 )    
            {
                Console.WriteLine("it's a little too small but i'm gonna take it anyways");
            }
            else if(size >= 40)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("it's a little too big but i'm gonna take it anyways");
            }
            else if ((color != "black" || color != "blue") && (size <= 38 || size >= 40))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the size is fine but i would prefer another color");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
    }

 }
}
```

every time I run it its like the others `else if` don't exist and I don't know how to fix this and I just cant  get it working. The only time it worked its when I used `else` without `if` in front of it but could only display a generic massage that was something like: *"hmm I think I'm gonna pass on buying this"* but I would prefer having something more specific.

Comment: you have an issue with your if else statment

Comment: Hint: `color != "black" || color != "blue"` is *always* true. (`color` can't be both black *and* blue at the same time.)

Comment: You, probably, mean `(color != "black" && color != "blue")` - any color except `black` and `blue`

Comment: Dean Van Greugen what issue?

Comment: Re "*every time I insert a size that's not 39*", The code you posted uses 39. Are you saying the code you posted works? Please fix to include the code that *doesn't* work!

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, I'm confused. 39 shouldn't do anything

Comment: Which of the branches do you expect to be taken?

Comment: Inegami its an example cause when i insert a different number it doesn't work

Comment: Why would you expect 39 to print to the console? Your logic here explicitly ignores 39. Is this a joke? All you will ever get for 39 is ReadLine()

Comment: @Tacchinus, Again, show the code that doesn't work, not the code that works. Replace the 39 with a number, tell us what output you get, and what output yet expect.

Comment: When I run it with 38/black it writes 'it's a little too small but i'm gonna take it anyways', as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Per the title, I wouldn't expect 39 to display anything either, as it is not accounted for in the if. It falls straight to the readline without satisfying any of the if's clauses.

That said, I think you are trying to ask too many questions at once of your if statement and combining the questions based on the size and the color. When you do this you wind up creating a matrix of scenarios which all permutations need to be accounted for, but that is not happening here explicitly (some being accounted for implicitly). Suggest you break these up so you can start to see more easily the gaps and overlaps in logic, such as if you change your size to 38 and color to green, you would expect it to satisfy the clause at l.23 `else if ((color != "black" || color != "blue") && (size <= 38 || size >= 40))`, but it wouldn't because 'size <= 38' has already been accounted for at l.15. Or that the clauses at l.11 'if (size == 40 && (color == "black" || color == "blue"))' and l.19 'else if (size >= 40)' overlap and implicitly satisfy l.19 based on a failed color test in a completely different clause.

My advise would be to choose a priority of size or color (guessing size), perform a top-level if on the size and then once you have your size determined, run any other logic needed for the color. Yes this will be more verbose, and (initially) require nested if statements but your intentions will be more clear; you wont have to do the mental gymnastics needed to parse all the permutations in your head just to be able to read the if statement.

Additionally, it would allow you to perhaps create a different method down the line that could perform the sizing questions for you.

Comment: Re "*Per the title, I wouldn't expect 39 to display anything either*", You misread. The title doesn't say that 39 displays nothing; it says that numbers other than 39 display nothing. The OP repeated this in the comments. This claim is clearly false.

Comment: What is "clearly false"? I simply stated that 39 would not display anything "either", which it wont, since it is not account for in the if, as I said. Perhaps you got hung up on the all but irrelevant 39 statement and didn't read the remainder of my post?

Comment: Re "*What is "clearly false"?*" The OP's claim that it doesn't display anything for numbers other than 39. Larger numbers will hit the first or third case. Smaller numbers, the second.

Comment: Re "*I simply stated that 39 would not display anything "either"*", No, that's not what you said. You said "Per the title, I wouldn't expect 39 to display anything either". This is wrong. The title doesn't say they expect 39 to display nothing. In fact, it says nothing at all for 39. It only talks about other values. This is why I suggested that you misread the title.

Answer (score 0):

I encapsulated your code in a `Test` method, and called it with different `size` values:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        for(int i = 35; i<=45; i++)
        {
            Test(i);
        }
    }

    static void Test(int size)
    {
        Console.Write("Test with {0}:", size);
        string color = "black";
        if (size == 40 && (color == "black" || color == "blue"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ok, i'm gonna take it");
        }
        else if (size <= 38 )    
        {
            Console.WriteLine("it's a little too small but i'm gonna take it anyways");
        }
        else if(size >= 40)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("it's a little too big but i'm gonna take it anyways");
        }
        else if ((color != "black" || color != "blue") && (size <= 38 || size >= 40))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the size is fine but i would prefer another color");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
Test with 35: it's a little too small but i'm gonna take it anyways
Test with 36: it's a little too small but i'm gonna take it anyways
Test with 37: it's a little too small but i'm gonna take it anyways
Test with 38: it's a little too small but i'm gonna take it anyways
Test with 39:
Test with 40: ok, i'm gonna take it
Test with 41: it's a little too big but i'm gonna take it anyways
Test with 42: it's a little too big but i'm gonna take it anyways
Test with 43: it's a little too big but i'm gonna take it anyways
Test with 44: it's a little too big but i'm gonna take it anyways
Test with 45: it's a little too big but i'm gonna take it anyways
```

I don't really get why you seem to say there is no output when you pick something different from 39. To me it looks like it's the contrary

Comment: For me it was like this with the original program so i don't know but thanks a lot.